# What is the order of this pole at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the order of the pole:

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(6\sin (z)-6z+z^3)^3}\,\, 
\mathrm{at}\, z=0$$

I thought about doing the expansion for sin and then pulling out a $z$ from there to get an order of $3$, but I'm not sure if that is correct. Is it?

Comment: You are right to try an expansion, but make sure to do it thoroughly.

Comment: Is the pole of order 18?

Comment: What about $6.(z-z^3/6+z^5/120-z^7/5040...)-6z+z^3$ ?

Comment: Nevermind I took the wrong coefficient, you are really smart

Comment: why do you even bother asking if you mess up your question after getting it solved??

Comment: Do not remove the question after it is answered; I have rolled back the edit deleting all the content.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}+O_{0}(z^7)
$$

from which
$$
6\sin z-6z+z^3\sim_{0}6\frac{z^5}{5!}
$$
Thus the order of the pole $z_0=0$ of
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{(6\sin z-6z+z^3)^3}
$$
is the same order of $z_0=0$ of
$$
g(z)=\frac1{(6/5!z^5)^3}=\frac{5!/6}{z^{15}}
$$
that is $15$.

Comment: This is not right. You have implemented my hint, but somewhere between your second line and fourth line, changed $\frac6{5!}x^5$ to $\frac6{5!}x^3$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ at $0$ is
$$
\sin(x)=x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5+O\left(x^7\right)
$$
Compute the Taylor expansion for $\left(6\sin(x)-6x+x^3\right)^3$.